# Which approach is better - More conditions or More Variables?

Tags: c

I had to write one function to get the largest among four numbers. I find two ways to do that -

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                        
int main() 
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d);
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);
    return 0;
}

int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
    int result,result2,result3;
    if(a>b)
        result=a;
    else
        result=b;
    if(result>c)
        result2=result;
    else
        result2=c;
    if(result2>d)
        result3=result2;
    else
        result3=d;
    return result3;
}
```

Or I can write the function like this also -

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d) 
{
    int greatest_int;
    if (a>b && a>c && a>d)
        greatest_int=a;
    else if (b>c && b>d)
        greatest_int=b;
    else if (c>d)
        greatest_int=c;
    else
        greatest_int=d;

    return greatest_int;
}
```

May I know which would be the better as in the first function I am using more variables and in the next one I am using more conditions. I tried running both & they are taking same amount of time so I couldn't differentiate between the two. As I am just starting with programming with C it would be good to know this as I go forward. Thank You.

Comment: "better" from what perspective?

Comment: How about using an array...

Comment: Neither, use arrays and loops. Also, if you've just started with C programming then don't worry about program efficiency.

Comment: @zerkms I was thinking about the program efficiency.

Comment: I cannot understand why it's being downvoted. He's asking to learn. And while doing this, he shares his code and explains what is his problem clearly. Please don't be so cruel.

Comment: @Y.Doktur 'He's asking to learn', sure, but we are not qualified to teach.  'explains what is his problem clearly' no, and that is why, I suspect, the Q was downvoted: 'which would be the better' is not defined.  Maybe RAM is in short supply in OP's embedded system, or perhaps overall run time is important, or possibly, (always my favourite), the OP wants the code that is easiest to debug.  'program efficiency' is no better: the code/data that is easiest to debug is obviously more efficient in terms of development time/money.  I did not downvote, but I do understand why many would.

Comment: @MartinJames I don't think so. He says that he's a newbie. Even if not, we can understand it from his question of course. Nobody should expect that a such a detailed "better" clarification from a newbie. An answer like 4386427 did is very welcomed. If we are here to help, we could do like him. Of course, nobody have to do it. But, otherwise, snapping at OPs or downvoting is not more than discouriging the newbies. That my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which approach is better - More conditions or More Variables?

First you need to define what you mean by **better**

Is it better performance?

Is it less memory usage?

Is it better maintenance?

Guessing about performance by looking at the C code is something that you shouldn't do - especially when being new to C. The compiler makes all kinds of optimizations on your C code, so there is (nearly) no way to predict performance. The only solution is to profile.

The same apply to memory usage - even though you define some variables, the compiler is likely to optimize them away. You'll have to inspect the generated assembler code to get an answer.

Regarding maintenance - in nearly all cases this is where you should focus. Make sure that your code is easy to understand (and their by to maintain). Performance issues come second.

Let's look at this code:

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
    int result,result2,result3;
    if(a>b)
        result=a;
    else
        result=b;
    if(result>c)
        result2=result;
    else
        result2=c;
    if(result2>d)
        result3=result2;
    else
        result3=d;
    return result3;
}
```

Here you say that you worry about the number of variables...

Well let's rewrite the code - let's pretend I'm a compiler.

The first thing I notice is that once `result` is initialized, the variable `a` isn't used anymore. So why introduce a new variable `result` when I have `a` available already. So instead of `result` I simply use `a` and rewrite to:

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
    int result2,result3;
    if(a>b)
        a=a;
    else
        a=b;
    if(a>c)
        result2=a;
    else
        result2=c;
    if(result2>d)
        result3=result2;
    else
        result3=d;
    return result3;
}
```

Now the first `if` is rather strange, so I rewrite to:

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
    int result2,result3;
    if(b >= a) a=b;
    if(a>c)
        result2=a;
    else
        result2=c;
    if(result2>d)
        result3=result2;
    else
        result3=d;
    return result3;
}
```

Once again I notice that once `result2` is initialized, the variable `a` isn't used anymore. So I can repeat the pattern from above and get rid of `result2` by replacing it by `a`. After that I can repeat the same pattern to get rid of `result3` and my code looks:

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
    if(b >= a) a = b;
    if(c >= a) a = c;
    if(d >= a) a = d;
    return a;
}
```

Still worried about the number of variables?

Since the compiler can see when the various variables are still in use (or no longer in use), the compiler may optimize your original code just like above by reusing "dead" variables.

But... the compiler will probably do something even more optimal. What? I don't know before I take a look at the generated assembly code.

So the conclusion is - don't look at the C code when finding the **better** way.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.  Have an upboat:)

Answer (score 4):

Or you can write this:

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d) 
{
    int greatest_int = a;
    if (b > greatest_int) {
        greatest_int = b;
    }
    if (c > greatest_int) {
        greatest_int = c;
    }
    if (d > greatest_int) {
        greatest_int = d;
    }
    return greatest_int;
}
```

Or something like this...

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d) 
{
    int greatest_int = a;
    int *iter = (int[]){b, c, d}, *end = iter + 3;
    for (; iter < end; iter ++) {
        if (*iter > greatest_int) {
            greatest_int = *iter;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

int f(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return max(max(max(a, b), c), d);
}
```